# Big Query Display result for data's that does not contain certain words

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a big query data which contains 2 columns, `MyText` and `SenderID`. The tablename is `mydatatable`. I managed to filter the message list of rows that contain the word `PIN` or `CODE` in the `MyText` table id.

This was done like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `mydatatable` 
WHERE Mytext LIKE '%PIN%' OR Mytext LIKE '%CODE%'
```

How do we display the list of rows that do **not** contain the word "PIN" or "CODE"?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM mydatatable WHERE NOT (Mytext LIKE '%PIN%' OR Mytext LIKE '%CODE%')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikhail-berlyant I modified it a bit and its working     SELECT * FROM `mydatatable` WHERE NOT Messagetext LIKE '%PIN%' OR Messagetext LIKE '%CODE%'